# Evaluating an integral.

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate $$\iint_{D}^\ y^3(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}} dx\, dy$$

on $D$, the region determined by the conditions $1/2\leq y\leq 1$ and $x^2+y^2\leq 1$

My book suggested we use $y^2=u$, but I don't know how to evaluate it, and I would really like to know the process.

Comment: above is y^3 * {(x^2+y^2)}^(-3/2)

Comment: Try to use polar coordinates.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I think polar coordinates are not best here, because of the limit $y \in [1/2,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

This may be done in rectangular coordinates.  The integral looks like

$$\int_{1/2}^1 dy \, y^3 \, \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \frac{dx}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} $$

To evaluate the inner integral, use a trig substitution such as $x=y \tan{t}$.  If you do everything correctly, you should get

$$2 \int_{1/2}^1 dy \, y \, \sqrt{1-y^2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

By the way, this is where that substitution suggested by your book comes in handy.